# Regex for finding repeated words without spaces

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex that allows me to find strings with repeated 'words' separated with no spaces ie:

wordwordword
wordword

Is this something possible?, if so any ideas would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is repeated word here?

Comment: I'd rather use word boundaries if possible and lazy `+` quantifier for *one or more*: [`\b(\w+?)\1+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/q5NC8g/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this expression (javascript):

```
/(.*)\1+/gm
```

The `(.*)` captures anything and looks for one or more repetition of that captured group with the `\1+`

See the example at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1hQJ6M/1)

Keep in mind that this returns empty strings also. To avoid that filter them out.

JS:

```
"This text hashashas many repeated wordswords".match(/(.*)\1+/gm).filter(x=>x.length>0)
```

Will return

```
[ "hashashas", "wordswords" ]
```

**Edit:**
@Lithis is right in both comments. Changing the `*` to a `+` will avoid capturing empty characters. And in order to avoid capturing repeated letters the best solution is to add a boundary `\b` at both ends of the regex (as stated by @bobble bubble).

Regex:

```
\b(.+)\1+\b
```

Comment: Changing the `*` to a `+` will avoid matching empty strings.

Comment: This will match any doubled letters within a word. Try it on the string `"This text hashashas many repeated wordswords and letters too"`.